# How do I replace a character contained within a DIV, and replace with a image, using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I was wondering if there is a way of replacing plain text in a `div.number-plate`, with a image for every character(one by one)? I am using JQuery

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Are you building a ransom note generator?

Comment: Hi Nick, basically I have a list of car number plates as plain text, each within a DIV. I am trying to replace each character in the DIV with a image. e.g. character 'A' with an image of itself, hence 'A.gif'. Please let me know if you need me to clarify further, Thanks

Comment: @Nasir - I felt you were just confused and *actually* needed a ransom note generator anyway, so I made you one: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/9qwFY/11/

Comment: @Nick - How do I get around having spaces in between the characters e.g. 'P7 XTR'? Is there a way of replacing empty spaces with gif ?

Comment: @Nasir - You can add space like this: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/9qwFY/13/ Or like this check, just return you space gif `<img>` instead of `m`: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/9qwFY/12/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since @AndyE laid down the code golf gauntlet here, you can use a regex to replace all the chacters with images, like this:

```
$("div.number-plate").html(function(i, h) {
    return h.replace(/(.)/g, '<img src="images/char-$1.gif" />');
});
```

[You can test it out here](https://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/9qwFY/).

---

Also, it seems *you* didn't want a ransom note generator, but I did! [so here it is](https://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/9qwFY/11/). Sample result:
http://www.joshuarey.com/ransom/w/2.gifhttp://www.joshuarey.com/ransom/e/3.gif [image]
<sub>(source: [joshuarey.com](http://www.joshuarey.com/ransom/h/8.gif))</sub>
http://www.joshuarey.com/ransom/a/13.gifhttp://www.joshuarey.com/ransom/v/5.gif[image]
<sub>(source: [joshuarey.com](http://www.joshuarey.com/ransom/e/15.gif))</sub>
 [image]
<sub>(source: [joshuarey.com](http://www.joshuarey.com/ransom/y/1.gif))</sub>
[image]
<sub>(source: [joshuarey.com](http://www.joshuarey.com/ransom/o/8.gif))</sub>
[image]
<sub>(source: [joshuarey.com](http://www.joshuarey.com/ransom/u/5.gif))</sub>
http://www.joshuarey.com/ransom/r/3.gif http://www.joshuarey.com/ransom/d/4.gif[image]
<sub>(source: [joshuarey.com](http://www.joshuarey.com/ransom/o/4.gif))</sub>
http://www.joshuarey.com/ransom/g/2.gif

Comment: +1 for going above and beyond! BTW, when can I have my dog back? :P

Comment: @Nick @Andy You guys crack me up!

Comment: @Nick - A gazillion Thanks...People this guy is a genius

Answer (score 6):

```
var div = $("div.number-plate"),
    txt = div.text(),
    pre = '<img src="images/char-',
    suf = '.gif">',
    result = pre + txt.split("").join(suf+pre) + suf;

div.html(result);
```

Sample number plate:

> V332LAE

Sample result:

[image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

It's a short, simple solution in which you would also need images for punctuation characters if they exist in your text.  Since you're working with number plates, that shouldn't be an issue.

Thanks to @Nick for introducing me to http://dummyimage.com, I've set up a demo of my own:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/aCdLR/

Comment: This is great! +1. Though what would make this *really* cool is to also set the char to be the `alt` attribute of each image :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var charMap = {
  'A': 'A.gif', 'B': 'B.gif' // ... etc.
}

$("div.number-plate").each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text(); // Assuming no HTML content
  var out = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = text.length; i < len; i++) {
    var img= charMap[text.charAt(i)];
    if (img) out.push("<img src='" + img + "'>");
  } 
  $(this).html(out.join(""));
});
```

(untested)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var str = $('div.number-plate').html();
  var output = '';

  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var char = str.substr(i, 1);
    output = output + '<img src="/images/characters/' + char + '.gif" />';
  }

  $('div.number-plate').html(output);           
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to transform each character (or filter out non-alnums) the [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) could be used:

```
$('.number-plate').html(function(i, o) {
    var imgs = $.map(o.split(''), function(c) {
        return '<img src="images/' + c.toLowerCase() + '.png" />';
    });
    return imgs.join('');
});
```

Characters can be filtered out by returning `NULL` in the mapping function.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/BVdJb/) - [with dummy images](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/BVdJb/1/) (no reason to use `$.map()`, though))